# Express: Pretty print json output

Tags: json, node.js, express

I could swear that res.send and res.json would pretty-print the output as default when I used it before.  However, I can't seem to get it to work this time.  I also read that `app.locals.pretty=true;` should do it as well, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's some sample code:

```
var express = require('express'); var app = express();

var sample_data ={
        widget: {
                child: {
                        title: "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
                        name: "Das Widget",
                }
        } };

app.locals.pretty = true;

app.get('/pretty', function(req, res){
        res.json(sample_data); });



var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port, function(){
        console.log('Listening on port ' + port); });
```

Comment: Are you trying to view this in stdout console or the browser?

Comment: In the browser, view->source, and with curl.

Comment: If you're using Chrome or Safari or Firefox, there are fantastic extensions to view JSON like JSONViewer. This won't work with embedded JSON on the DOM but works well for API endpoints.

Comment: Also, here's a nice article on doing it via command line with curl. http://jimpravetz.com/blog/2010/11/curl-json-and-pretty-print/